# Getting the SSJS value from a for loop and assign it a ampscript variable

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email-template, ssjs, marketingcloudapi

I have a requirement, I need to encrypt a data field value from the behavioral trigger Abandoned cart and after extracting the JSON body, I have to use the product information in the email template. Below is my SSJS code:

```
<!--%%[
SET @data1 = AttributeValue("data")
Set @data = Concat('{"trigger_payload":', '"' ,@data1, '"',
'}')
]%% -->


<script runat="server">
  Platform.Load("Core", "1") 
   var data = Platform.Variable.GetValue("@data");
  var protocol = "https";
  var mid = "*****";
  var hostname = mid + ".recs.igodigital.com";
  var url = protocol + "://" + hostname + "/" + mid + "/trigger"
  var result = HTTP.Post(url, "application/json", data, []);
  
  if (result.StatusCode == 200) {
      var obj = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(result.Response[0]);
                
            for(var responseField in obj) {
                        var value = obj[responseField];
                        if(responseField === "products" || responseField === "current_cart") {
                             var prefix = (responseField === "products") ? "@item_" : "@cart_";
                                for(var i=0; i<value.length; i++) {
                                    for(var itemField in value[i]) {
                                        var name = prefix + itemField + "_" + (i+1);
                                        var val = value[i][itemField];
                                        Platform.Variable.SetValue(name, val);
                
            
                                    }
                                }
                        }
                        else{
                             Platform.Variable.SetValue("@"+responseField, value);
                            }
            }
    }
    else{
          Write("failed http request:" );
          
        }
       
      
    
    </script>


sample json :

{
    "products": [
        {
            "link": "XXXXX",
            "image_link": "YYYY",
            "product_code": "34380021",
            "name": "AAA",
            "regular_price": 85.0,
            "sale_price": 85.0,
            "sku_id": "34380021",
            "online_availability": "Y",
            "quantity": 1,
            "amount": "85.00"
        }
    ],
    "current_cart": [],
    "same_products": "N",
    "user": {},
    "purchased": false,
    "abandoned_items": "34380021",
    "tracking_pixel": "<img src=''
}
```

I want to use the values  that have been set in below in name varaible in the email template.Can someone please help me on this.

Platform.Variable.SetValue(name, val)

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're trying to achieve. What's the "encryption" piece you're looking to do? Where does AMPScript come in? What's the point of the loop, if you're only interested in the final iteration's data?

Comment: Hi Macca, We implemented behavioral abandoned cart functionality, this DE has a data field that is encrypted. After the decryption of the data field, i  got JSON which i have updated in my decption. From this JSON, i need the products details to be used as dynamical field in the email template.